# How can I use OOP PHP in this contact form?

Tags: php

```html
        <div class="form">
          <div id="errormessage"></div>
          <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="btnsubmit">Send Message</button></div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

This is the contact for I have database name msolution and table user 
how can I use OOP PHP for this contact form 
Please if any one can help me in this by providing the code and thank you for your help

Comment: What you're asking is off-topic for **many** reasons. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I want to say is that it doesn't make sense to ask how to apply OOP to a form; what I guess you need is an example of a script PHP that uses OOP to handle the data from the form.

Hoping you are just making you first steps, I wanna help you for this time.

To begin, you can declare the class you need in a ContactForm.php file; this class should have a property for any field you have in the contact form, all protected and with their own setter and getter method in respect of "Encapsulation" concept:

```
<?php

class ContactForm {
    protected $name;
    protected $email;
    protected $subject;
    protected $message;

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
    // do the same for email, subject and message fields
}
```

Once you have this class you can write a script contact.php that includes the ContactForm.php class and use it to work with data from the POST HTTP:

```
<?php

require 'ContactForm.php'; // assuming they are in the same folder

$contactForm = new ContactForm();
$contactForm->setName($_POST['name']);
// do the same for email, subject and message fields

// after all set, you can use getters if you need to work with the data in the class, example:
$contactForm->getName();
```

A few consideration:

- Check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) if you don't know what Encapsulation is
- This is a very generic example with the name only, but following the comments you can add all fields you need
- I didn't consider any security check: you should validate data from $_POST before using it in order to prevent bad data and attacks

Hope I was clear, if not let me know.

Comment: and after that what I need to do dear

Comment: As some users noticed in comments, this is not free code writing service: take my snippets and study  make some tests and some steps forward on your own, then ask a REAL question, not to do the job for you.